# .Net MAUI iOS app - file upload inside WebView not uploading file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, maui

It's an .Net iOS app. Inside the app, I'm trying to run a web application inside WebView and after I select the image in Photo Library, it is not returns to page, just showing loading icon and doesn't upload the image. Android part works fine.

MainPage.xaml

```
<WebView Loaded="WebView_Loaded"
     x:Name="myWebView">
</WebView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void LoadWebView()
{
    myWebView.Source = "URL";
}

    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();

#if ANDROID
        var webview = myWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
        webview.SetWebChromeClient(new myApp.Platforms.Android.MyWebChromeClient(MainActivity.Instance));

        if (webview is not null)
        {
            webview.Settings.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false;
            webview.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);
            webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        }
#endif

    }
```

Not sure what's setting do I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the relevant code